# Does 'docker start' execute the CMD command?

Tags: docker

Let's say a docker container has been run with `docker run` and then stopped with `docker stop`. Will the `CMD` command be executed after a `docker start`?

Comment: Check this question: [What is the difference between CMD and ENTRYPOINT in a Dockerfile?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21553353/4677231) Great for understanding `CMD`,`ENTRYPOINT`

Comment: Might be helpful: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/76919

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I believe @jripoll is incorrect, it appears to run the command that was first run with `docker run` on `docker start` too.

Here's a simple example to test:

First create a shell script to run called `tmp.sh`:

```
echo "hello yo!"
```

Then run:

```
docker run --name yo -v "$(pwd)":/usr/src/myapp -w /usr/src/myapp ubuntu sh tmp.sh
```

That will print `hello yo!`.

Now start it again:

```
docker start -ia yo
```

It will print it again every time you run that.

### Same thing with Dockerfile

Save this to Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine

CMD ["echo", "hello yo!"]
```

Then build it and run it:

```
docker build -t hi .
docker run -i --name hi hi
```

You'll see "hello yo!" output. Start it again:

```
docker start -i hi
```

And you'll see the same output.

Comment: I think you are correct, but that example does not explain the OP's question.  In your case `echo "hello yo!"` will immediately *complete*, and therefore stop itself.  The OP was asking what happens when you stop a container "mid-stream" with the `docker stop` command.  Think of a web server that you stop with `docker stop`.  I *think* it does exactly what you are saying, @Travis... it restarts the CMD or ENTRYPOINT. But I do want to test this myself to see.  I had the same question.

Comment: Added same example using Dockerfile @MikeWilliamson

Comment: Thanks, @Travis.  In this case, aren't you again just running it twice (the `docker run` completes, then the `docker start` runs)?  Again, I thought the OP was asking what `docker start` and `docker stop` do when *mid-stream* in running the container code. For instance, if there are 300 lines of source code and you stop it 150 lines into that code, what does `start` do?  I am 99% sure it does as you are saying: it starts from the very beginning again and will operate exactly the same as the first pass through (unless any connected volumes have changed, etc).

Comment: I don't know how you'd stop it a few a hundred lines into your code, I'm assuming the OP was talking about some long running daemon like an HTTP server. But regardless, it appears the command will run again. The big difference between `run` and `start` is that `run` creates a new container, `start` uses an existing one.

Answer (score 8):

When you do a docker start, you call [`api/client/start.go`](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/4a9523adc90de8fea1de23b5e33ae184bdd9f25e/api/client/start.go#143), which calls:

```
 cli.client.ContainerStart(containerID)
```

That calls [`engine-api/client/container_start.go`](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/131e2bf12b2e1b3ee31b628a501f96bbb901f479/vendor/src/github.com/docker/engine-api/client/container_start.go#L5):

```
cli.post("/containers/"+containerID+"/start", nil, nil, nil)
```

The docker daemon process that API call in [`daemon/start.go`](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/1f2917602e5319a5d6d26caa52e7c964f120b5e5/daemon/start.go#L157):

```
container.StartMonitor(daemon, container.HostConfig.RestartPolicy)
```

The container monitor does run the container in [`container/monitor.go`](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/67d6154cc26cceccc554ebb54ae4dcbad44047e4/container/monitor.go#L183):

```
m.supervisor.Run(m.container, pipes, m.callback)
```

By default, the docker daemon is the supervisor here, in [daemon/daemon.go](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/117a982d2e805d3279ff75fcec071635e5191ef6/daemon/daemon.go#L941):

```
daemon.execDriver.Run(c.Command, pipes, hooks)
```

And the execDriver creates the command line in [`daemon/execdriver/windows/exec.go`](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/dfebb6074f62891368cb3c668380c186f3bebb33/daemon/execdriver/windows/exec.go#L37):

```
createProcessParms.CommandLine, err = createCommandLine(processConfig, false)
```

That uses the `processConfig.Entrypoint` *and* `processConfig.Arguments` in [`daemon/execdriver/windows/commandlinebuilder.go`](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/ad8a66573c61483b9a0721470438dfc8bd01993f/daemon/execdriver/windows/commandlinebuilder.go#L23-L32):

```
// Build the command line of the process
commandLine = processConfig.Entrypoint
logrus.Debugf("Entrypoint: %s", processConfig.Entrypoint)
for _, arg := range processConfig.Arguments {
    logrus.Debugf("appending %s", arg)
    if !alreadyEscaped {
        arg = syscall.EscapeArg(arg)
    }
    commandLine += " " + arg
}
```

Those `ProcessConfig.Arguments` are populated in [`daemon/container_operations_windows.go`](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/7a97e938e2229fa7a50b0f6e66c70eddcb9d2dc2/daemon/container_operations_windows.go#L77-L82):

```
processConfig := execdriver.ProcessConfig{
    CommonProcessConfig: execdriver.CommonProcessConfig{
        Entrypoint: c.Path,
        Arguments:  c.Args,
        Tty:        c.Config.Tty,
    },
```

, with `c.Args` being the arguments of a Container (runtile parameters or `CMD`)

So yes, the '`CMD`' commands are executed after a '`docker start`'.

Comment: Docker start runs both `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD`. If you don't specify `ENTRYPOINT`, it uses the default one instead (`/bin/sh -c`).

Answer (score 0):

If you would like your container to run the same executable every time, then you should consider using `ENTRYPOINT` in combination with `CMD`.

Note: don’t confuse `RUN` with `CMD`. RUN actually runs a command and commits the result; `CMD` does not execute anything at build time, but specifies the intended command for the image.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/

Answer (score -2):

No, the CMD command only executed when you execute 'docker run' to run a container based in a image.

In the documentation:
When used in the shell or exec formats, the CMD instruction sets the command to be executed when **running the image**.

https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#cmd

Comment: `docker start` also runs the image.